# Can vertical asymptotes only exist on one side of the axis?

Tags: calculus

In my school's mathematics theory, it says that when identifying a horizontal asymptote, one must specify whether it exists in $-\infty$, $+\infty$, or both. But when it comes to vertical asymptotes, they ask for no such precision. Is that deliberate?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\; \textrm{if}\; x\leq 0 \\
\frac{1}{x},\; \textrm{if}\; x>0
\end{cases}$$

You have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)=0$.

We have a horizonal asymptote in $0$ only by the right side (try to draw the graph)

Comment: So I should specify on which side it exists because it is possible (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: And would it not be a vertical asymptote in 0?

Comment: I don't know if, formally, a function has a vertical asymptote in $a$ if the limit to $a$ go to $\pm\infty$ both sides or it's sufficient the one-sided limit.

Comment: More important that the formally name is you understanding the idea and my counter-example